# Retrieve data from multi level inner list using java8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have List of `Employee`s , each employee has a list of `Department`s in it, each department has a list of `location`, I want to fetch the list of location based on some filter condition.

Here is my code -

```
for (Employee empl : employeeList) {
    if(empl.getEmployeeName().equals("XXX")) {
        for (Department dept : empl.getDepartmets()) {
            if(dept.getDepartmentName().equals("Sales")) {
                return dept.getLocations();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to handle this on java8 steam api , can anyone help ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I coded the logic with out stream API , i want this to be handled this logic in java8 stream

Answer (score 3):

```
employeeList.stream()
          .filter(x -> "XXX".equals(x.getEmployeeName()))
          .flatMap(x -> x.getDepartmets().stream().filter(y -> "Sales".equals(y.getDepartmentName())))
          .findFirst()
          .map(Department::getLocations)
          .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

The only point would be that `flatMap` is not really lazy until [java-10](/questions/tagged/java-10) if you really care about this and I *assume* `locations` is a `List` of some type here.

Comment: is that returning the List<Locations> , getting error for me


List<Locations> locations = employeeList.stream().filter(x -> "XXX".equals(x.getEmployeeName())).flatMap(x -> x.getDepartmets().stream().filter(y -> "Sales".equals(y.getDepartmentName()))).findFirst().orElse(null);

Comment: @aruntheimperfect you are not getting the list . findFirst will return department object

Comment: @Eugene sorry I didnt meant your code . check arun comment

Comment: @aruntheimperfect you missed a `map(Department::getLocations)`

Comment: @aruntheimperfect you could [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a `Stream<Employee>` from the `employeeList`
2. `filter` this stream to retain only employees where their name is "XXX"
3. map/flatten the `Stream<Employee>` into a `Stream<Department>`
4. filter this list of departments to retain the item where the department name is equal to `"Sales"`
5. get the find matching item with `findFirst`
6. map to `Department::getLocations` which you can then get the value the Optional contains with calls to `orElse` providing a default value or `ifPresent` or whatever is sufficient in your use case.

Code:

```
   employeeList.stream()  // step 1
               .filter(e -> e.getEmployeeName().equals("XXX")) // step 2
               .flatMap(e -> e.getDepartmets().stream()) // step 3
               .filter(d -> "Sales".equals(d.getDepartmentName())) // step 4
               .findFirst() // step 5
               .map(Department::getLocations); // step 6
```

Comment: it should  be  `"Sales".equals(d.getDepartmentName()`?

Comment: @Aomine and that is not a direct transplantation of the previous code, not until `java-10` when `flatMap` became lazy...

Comment: @Eugene don’t unsettle beginners, the code is sufficient, whether the implementation is lazy or not.

Comment: @manfromnowhere, as said by Eugene OP, changed it after my answer. I've edited it now. thanks.

Comment: it helps . made it work with few adjustment , 

List<Locations> locations = employeeList.stream().filter(e -> e.getEmployeeName().equals("Arun")).flatMap(e -> e.getDepartmets().stream()).filter(d -> "Marketting".equals(d.getDepartmentName())).findFirst().map(Department :: getLocations).orElse(null);

Comment: `.filter(e -> e.getEmployeeName().equals("XXX"))` better to swap left and right values to avoid NPE inside the stream pipeline.

Comment: @aruntheimperfect as said, in the answer, you'll need to invoke `orElse` or some other appropriate method to get the actual value inside the Optional, just returning after the `map` call above will not suffice unless your method has an Optional return type which I doubt it does. Anyway good that you've got it working...